# Laravel eloquent how to order collection by accessor in appends array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have following Eloquent model:

```
class Song extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'mg_songs';
protected $hidden = array('events');
protected $appends = array('lastDate');

public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Event', 'song_event');
}

public function getLastDateAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->events) return null;

    return $this->events[0]->date->formatLocalized('%d.%m.%Y (%a, %Hч)');
}}
```

Is it possible to sort by "lastdate" field same as db field:

```
$songs->orderBy('title', 'asc'); - works
$songs->orderBy('lastDate', 'desc'); - doesn't works
```

May be exist simple answer?

**EDITED:**

My db structure (only needed fields), with many-to-many:

**events table**
event_id
date

**songs table**
song_id
title

**song_event pivot table**
id
song_id
event_id

SQL-request:

```
SELECT s.title, (SELECT MAX(e.date) FROM events e JOIN song_event se ON (e.id = se.event_id) WHERE se.song_id = s.id) AS s_date FROM mg_songs s ORDER BY s_date desc
```

Answer (score 20):

You can sort the resulting collection by accessor, obviously the query can't be ordered, for it's not in the db.

```
$songs = Song::all(); // get the result
$songs->sortByDesc('lastDate'); // sort using collection method

// or ascending:
$songs->sortBy('lastDate');
```

You could achieve the same using `joins`, if you prefer to do this in the db call (it's better in terms of performance).

---

Another thing: you use `if( ! $this->events)` which will cause trouble soon.

Check this out:

```
// hasOne / belongsTo / morphTo etc - single relations
$model->relation; // returns related model OR null -> evaluates to false

// BUT for hasMany / belongsToMany etc - multiple results
$model->relation; // always returns a collection, even if empty, evaluates to true
```

So change this `if` to:

```
public function getLastDateAttribute()
{
    if ( ! count($this->events)) return null;

    return $this->events[0]->date->formatLocalized('%d.%m.%Y (%a, %Hч)');
}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And What you mean about same using joins? See above, three tables and right SQL-request

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to get songs with last date (related record from events where date is max) for them. Then I want to provide to user sorting result by title song (no problem) and last date of song.

Comment: In Laravel 5 the `sortBy()` returns the sorted instance of the Collection, so you will need to use: `$songs = $songs->sortBy('lastDate');`