# How to add a new field to a Model and use it in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, append

I'm trying the following: I have a model, called Pub, that has the following fields: "id","name","address","longitude","latitude","schedule","photo", etc.

As I need to know the distance between Pub and User, so I've created a function that calculates the distance in Pub Model using longitude and latitude:

```
public function pubDistance()
{
    $userLat = '';
    $userLong = '';

    $pubLat = $this->latitude;
    $pubLong = $this->longitude;

    if(!($userLat && $userLong))
    {
        $userLat = 40.4169473;
        $userLong = -3.7035285;
    }

    $earthRadius = 6371;

    $latFrom = deg2rad($userLat);
    $lonFrom = deg2rad($userLong);
    $latTo = deg2rad($pubLat);
    $lonTo = deg2rad($pubLong);

    $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
    $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

    $a = pow(cos($latTo) * sin($lonDelta), 2) +
        pow(cos($latFrom) * sin($latTo) - sin($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta), 2);

    $b = sin($latFrom) * sin($latTo) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta);

    $angle = atan2(sqrt($a), $b);

    $distance = round($angle * $earthRadius, 2);

    return $distance;

}
```

And I use this function here (inside Pub model too):

```
public function getPubDistanceToUserAttribute()
{
    return $this->pubDistance();
}
```

Then the problem I have is how to add the field to Pub model and use to order my pubs by distance.

The first thing I could do it appending:

```
protected $appends = ['pub_distance_to_user'];
```

But I'm having problems in my controller to order by that new field:

```
public function getPubs()
{
    $pubs = Pub::all();

    return $pubs;
}
```

This is what I have:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Dr. Nikko Braun",
"address": "453 Wyman Crossroad\nSouth Eliashaven, NY 75636",
"longitude": "118.9395890",
"latitude": "-62.3235600",
"schedule": "1986-11-13 10:15:48",
"photo": 
"email": "sylvester.rutherford@example.net",
"phone": "1-841-349-8925 x684",
"pub_distance_to_user": 15556.09
```

}

How I could use accesors and mutators here, or something like this in this case?...

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You know you can do the query with the query builder and calculate that field directly in the query through the magic of mysql, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you can add a field in the function `getPubs()` by using the foreach loop,

Try this,

```
public function getPubs()
{
    $pubs = Pub::all();

    foreach($pubs as $pub){
    $pub->pub_distance_to_user = Pub::pubDistance();
    }

    return $pubs->sortBy('pub_distance_to_user');
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think you can define your function to calcluate **distance** with arguments, like this way

```
public function pubDistance($pubLat,$pubLong)
{

$userLat = '';
$userLong = '';

if(!($userLat && $userLong))
{
    $userLat = 40.4169473;
    $userLong = -3.7035285;
}

$earthRadius = 6371;

$latFrom = deg2rad($userLat);
$lonFrom = deg2rad($userLong);
$latTo = deg2rad($pubLat);
$lonTo = deg2rad($pubLong);

$latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
$lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

$a = pow(cos($latTo) * sin($lonDelta), 2) +
    pow(cos($latFrom) * sin($latTo) - sin($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta), 2);

$b = sin($latFrom) * sin($latTo) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta);

$angle = atan2(sqrt($a), $b);

$distance = round($angle * $earthRadius, 2);

return $distance;

}
```

And then you have to call function by `Pub::pubDistance($pub->latitude,$pub->longitude);`

```
public function getPubs()
{
    $pubs = Pub::all();

    foreach($pubs as $pub){
    $pub->pub_distance_to_user = Pub::pubDistance($pub->latitude,$pub->longitude);
    }

    return $pubs->sortBy('pub_distance_to_user');
}
```

Comment: Sorry man, but it gives me the following message: "message": "Method [pubDistance] does not exist on [App\\Http\\Controllers\\PubsController]. in Controller.php (68)"

Comment: So Do you have `pub_distance_to_user` in database?

Comment: nop, I calculate pub_distance_to_user in a function using latitude and longitude that are in my database

Comment: I have updated my answer. Your calculation method is in the Pub Model So assigning that. Tell me if you find any difficulty.

Comment: hey brother!! is getting better, but the result is still the same because what you do inside foreach doesnt affect to what you return ($pubs->sortBy...) Im trying to fix it, but if you can help me a I'll be happy :D. Thanks

Comment: Great!! What should these fields contain `$userLat` and `$userLong` ?

Comment: user coordinates, but now Im using fixed values for testing

Comment: @BerTsacianegudelTepuy I have updated my answer have you checked it?

Comment: @BerTsacianegudelTepuy Have you solved your problem? And if solved! Did my answer help you?

Comment: Hi Chirag, thanks for your interesting, I had to change some issues...let me solve and I'll be telling you. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Please add below code with your table field in your model:

```
/**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['yorr_field1','yorr_field1','yorr_field3'];
```

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the issue he's asking, he wants to order the collection of pubs by closest pub using the `distance` accessor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this on the query, but it should be easy to do it on the collection:

```
$pubs = Pub::all()->sortBy(function ($pub) {
     return $pub->pubDistance();
});
```

Comment: I don't think the accessor exists at this point as it's a DB call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but it doesn't work: it gives me pubs listed in order by id :(

Comment: Is the result of `dd(Pub::all()->pluck('pub_distance_to_user'));` correct?

Answer (score 0):

Define this in your getPubs function, since `$pubs` is a collection we can use the sortBy/sortByDesc method to sort the collection by ascending or descending.  In this case we want ascending to have the lowest digit first.

Source: [Laravel Documentation / sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby)

Second Source: [Similar to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975542/laravel-eloquent-how-to-order-collection-by-accessor-in-appends-array)

```
public function getPubs()
{
    $pubs = Pub::all();
    $sorted = $pubs->sortBy('pub_distance_to_user');
    return $sorted;
}
```

Comment: If you want it descending you can `$pubs->sortByDesc('pub_distance_to_user`);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but it doesn't work: it gives me pubs listed in order by id :(

Comment: Mistake on my behalf, could you please try my updated code? What I have done is sort the array BEFORE returning it.