# How To Sort Accessors In Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have a Character Model Which have some Accessors which counts some items related to this model.
I cannot use orderby because column does not exist in db and cannot use sortby because we use datatables (with angular). In postgres may be possible with lateral join but am using mysql. Is any other way to do this ?
Accessors ex.

```
protected $appends = [
     "changes_count"
];

public function getChangesCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->changes()->where('type', 'Change')->count();
}

public function indexWithPagination(Request $request)
{
    //Sorting
    $column = isset($request->sortField) ? $request->sortField : null;
    $order_by = 'asc';
    if (isset($request->sortOrder)) {
        $order_by = $request->sortOrder === 1 ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    }

    $record = Character::with(Character::getRelationshipsArray());

    switch ($column) {
            case 'cast':
                $record->orderBy('character_number', $order_by);
                break;

            case 'changes_count':
                ??
                break;

            default:
                $record->orderBy($column, $order_by);
                break;
        }

        return getIndexWithPagination($record);
  }
```

Comment: Have you considered sorting the collection?

Comment: Technically that's an accessor ;)

Comment: yes sir its collection and yes Technically that's an accessor , i have datatable include searching filters and sorting all things working except these accessors

Comment: plz once read question have to make query like before get() method because m using custom datatable where only i have to send query there i cannot use sortby plz understand

Comment: maybe you should include more code so we understand it better what you are doing? ...

Comment: *" In postgres may be possible with lateral join but am using mysql."* ... also MysQL 8 supports lateral join it is called [Lateral Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) in the manual.. And in most non supporting RDMS you could write that as a corelated subquery most likely to emulate..

Comment: We need code of Character class aswell

Comment: Raymond Nijland   its very big query i can add some in short way plz check updated question

Comment: Raymond Nijland thanks for  Lateral Derived Tables  info  i tried and let u know

Comment: ... also why don't to add the `changes_count` column in MySQL with a VIEW ? And query that VIEW instead from Laravel..

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the resulting collection by accessor, obviously, the query can't be ordered, for it's not in the DB.

```
$record->sortByDesc('changes_count'); // sort using collection method

// or ascending:
$record->sortBy('changes_count');
```

You could achieve the same using joins if you prefer to do this in the DB call (it's better in terms of performance).

[Reference Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975542/laravel-eloquent-how-to-order-collection-by-accessor-in-appends-array)